# Unable to cd do sdcard with adb after update to Froyo

Tags: android, adb, sd-card, android-2.2-froyo

My application takes a picture and saves to the sdcard.  It worked fine on Android 2.1, but I just upgraded to Froyo and now I'm getting:

```
ERROR/CameraPreview(28216): Problem taking picture
WARN/System.err(28216): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/silviaterra/temp.jpg (Permission denied)
WARN/System.err(28216):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.openImpl(Native Method)
WARN/System.err(28216):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:152)
WARN/System.err(28216):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:97)
WARN/System.err(28216):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:69)
```

When I open up adb shell (as root user), I get:

```
$ cd sdcard
cd: can't cd to sdcard
$ cd mnt/sdcard
cd: can't cd to mnt/sdcard
```

I've tried killing and restarting the adb server, but no luck.  Any ideas on what's going on?  Thanks!

Comment: Please move to superuser

Comment: Why use this to superuser? He says that his applications does not work on froyo anymore.

Comment: How do you know the sdcard is being mounted on `/mnt`? I'd suggest using the `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` method in order to make sure the SD Card is mounted there.

Comment: Cristian, I am using that: String externalStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
  new File(externalStoragePath + STORAGE_DIR).mkdirs();
  filename = externalStoragePath + STORAGE_DIR + TEMPFILE_NAME;

Comment: Looking around further, I thought that it might be because Ubuntu is mounting the SD card on the operating system and so I can't mount it on the phone, but even when I unmount it from Ubuntu, still no dice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok - this one was a bit tricky.  Turns out that my "USB Connection Type" was "Disk drive", and so even though I had unmounted the sdcard from Ubuntu, I guess there was still a lock in place.  The trick is to just switch back to "Charge Only"